# how to add a new column on dataframe using a function

Tags: r, dataframe, function, conditional-statements

i need to create a column on a dataframe containing a conditional rule, that will apply only to the values of a singular column called "value".

i have already created the function, however when I try to add it to ne data frame I encounter the following error

```
fun <- function(x) { #function
     if(x < 10) {return ("white")
     } else if (x >= 10 && x < 30) {
       return ("yellow")
         } else if (x >= 30 && x < 50) {
           return ("red")
         } else {
             return ("black")
           }
}

#applying as a column on dataframe
dt$newcolumn <- apply(dt, 1, fun(dt$value))
```

error

```
  Error in if (x < 10) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
    In addition: Warning message:
    In if (x < 10) { :
      the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

I am prob. doing something wrong when applying the fucntion to the dataframe.

thanks in advance!

Comment: Use the vectorized version of `if` which is `ifelse`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The logical test in an `if` statement needs to evaluate to a single TRUE or FALSE, whereas in your case it evaluates to a vector of TRUE and FALSE, which is what causes the error. The vectorized equivalent is `ifelse`, but that is still not ideal here because you require nested ifelse statements. One can either use `switch` or `case_when` for the case of multiple options in the output, but the neatest base R solution here is probably just to use `cut`:

```r
fun <- function(x) {
  as.character(cut(x, c(-Inf, 10, 30, 50, Inf) - 0.000001, 
                   c('white', 'yellow', 'red', 'black')))
}

fun(1:100)
#> [1] "white"  "white"  "white"  "white"  "white"  "white"  "white"  "white" 
#> [9] "white"  "yellow" "yellow" "yellow" "yellow" "yellow" "yellow" "yellow"
#> [17] "yellow" "yellow" "yellow" "yellow" "yellow" "yellow" "yellow" "yellow"
#> [25] "yellow" "yellow" "yellow" "yellow" "yellow" "red"    "red"    "red"   
#> [33] "red"    "red"    "red"    "red"    "red"    "red"    "red"    "red"   
#> [41] "red"    "red"    "red"    "red"    "red"    "red"    "red"    "red"   
#> [49] "red"    "black"  "black"  "black"  "black"  "black"  "black"  "black" 
#> [57] "black"  "black"  "black"  "black"  "black"  "black"  "black"  "black" 
#> [65] "black"  "black"  "black"  "black"  "black"  "black"  "black"  "black" 
#> [73] "black"  "black"  "black"  "black"  "black"  "black"  "black"  "black" 
#> [81] "black"  "black"  "black"  "black"  "black"  "black"  "black"  "black" 
#> [89] "black"  "black"  "black"  "black"  "black"  "black"  "black"  "black" 
#> [97] "black"  "black"  "black"  "black"
```

Comment: hey allan! thank you once again for you soluton, but im afraid cut does not work. in the x <10 = "white", the cut function considers 19 as "white", while it should not.

Comment: @Geek_Nerdy93 I take it you mean 10 rather than 19. In any case, you can simply remove an arbitrarily tiny amount from the thresholds. See my update, where 10 is now yellow (so is 19), and both 30 and 50 are correct too

Comment: @Geek_Nerdy93 I simply reduced all the breaks in the cut argument by 0.00001 so that if the value of x is exactly 10, it will be above the cut. The way it was before, 10 was exactly on the cut, which puts it in the lower bin. Note that the logic of x < 10 is approximately the same as x <= 0.999999

Comment: how do I apply the new function you created to my dataframe? i tried with `dt$newcolumn <- apply(dt, 1, fun(dt$value))` and it didn't work. i got the error Error in match.fun(FUN) : 
 'fun(dt$value)' is not a function, character or symbol

Comment: What's wrong with `dt$newcolumn <- fun(df$value)` ?

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in comments you can use vectorised `ifelse` or `dplyr::case_when`  which will avoid the use of `apply` or any other loop. You can directly apply the function to whole column.

```
library(dplyr)

fun <- function(x) { #function
  case_when(x < 10 ~ "white", 
            between(x, 10, 29) ~ "yellow", 
            between(x, 30, 49) ~ "red", 
            TRUE ~ "black")
}
dt <- data.frame(value = c(5, 89, 30, 15))
dt$newcolumn <- fun(dt$value)
dt

#  value newcolumn
#1     5     white
#2    89     black
#3    30       red
#4    15    yellow
```

Comment: hi ronak! thanks for the answer. I cannot use any packages (sorry I forgot to specify in the question). is that a way that i can use `ifelse` with  multiple conditions?